# dropEvent not firing in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement Drag&Drop in my application, but the `dropEvent` in the target widget is never called.

I searched this problem a lot but every solution I found involves overriding `dragMoveEvent`, which I did, but with no difference.

This example code for me is not working either, for the above reason:

**Main window class:**

```py
class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 400, 200)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(DragLabel())
        self.layout().addWidget(DropTest())
```

**Label to drag:**

```py
class DragLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DragLabel, self).__init__()
        self.setText("Drag me")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText("Test drop")

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)

        dropAction = drag.exec(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)
```

**Widget to drop onto:**

```py
class DropTest(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DropTest, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        print("DragEnter")
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        print("DragMove")
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        print("DropEvent")
        position = e.pos()
        print(position)
        e.accept()
```

When I drag the label onto the other widget I see that both  `dragEnterEvent` and `dragMoveEvent` are being called, but when I actually drop the label I get no message from the `dropEvent` function.

Plus, after closing the window the application will hang and won't quit.

I'm using PyQt 5.13.1 x86_64 installed with DNF in Fedora 31. Python version is 3.7.5 with no virtualenv.

Comment: Although I don't like answers without explanations, the S.Nick code works for me. Have you copied, pasted and executed the S.Nick code without modifying it? Did it work for you or not? What version of PyQt5 do you use? What version of Python3 do you use? Are you using any IDE or do you run it in the terminal? You should place the characteristics of your environment to analyze if it is a bug, what version of fedora do you use? How have you installed PyQt5? Do you use the PyQt5 of the system or do you use pip, conda or other environment?

Comment: Thank you, I will add these details to the question right now. By the way no, S.Nick's example doesn't work for me even though I copy pasted the code into a blank file with no modifications and run it from terminal with python3.

Comment: I just tried it on a docker with fedora 31 and it works, it doesn't work in the most beautiful way but it works, maybe you expect the dragged text to be displayed. What I observe is that when the left label is pressed, then drag the mouse to the right label (the dragged text will not be seen) and when you release the mouse in the middle of the right label it will change the text from "Accepts Drop" to " Drag me."

Comment: No what I expect is "dropEvent" to be printed after "dragEnter" and "dragMove", which doesn't happen, meaning the event is not being called. Or at least I wish the application wouldn't hang but exit cleanly when I close the window.

Comment: While in Nick's example I don't even see the text change...

Comment: Remembering that I once answered the same question and fortunately I found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244614/6622587,  try my solution and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: Funny enough that answer already had my upvote from the past days. So no, that example didn't work either... Could it be a bug in my Qt verision then?

Comment: As I indicated, I have tested it on a docker with fedora 31 using the pyqt5 (PyQt5 5.13.1) installed by the system (using dnf) and it works correctly.

Comment: Here comes my dumbness: I guess both? It was previously installed from DNF, but I'm pretty sure setuptools also installed it from pip as a dependency of my application

Comment: mmm, uninstall both and reinstall with dnf. Fedora to distribute PyQt5 does not use the one that provides pip but compiles it from the source code so they can have different flags that can generate what you point out.

Comment: Ok this actually worked. Go ahead and post it as a question so I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in a comment I had already answered the same question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244614/6622587), and I have tested it in a docker with fedora31 and it works correctly so after a discussion with the OP he pointed out it in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702040/dropevent-not-firing-in-pyqt5?noredirect=1#comment103794068_58702040):

> [PyQt5] was previously installed from
>   DNF, but I'm pretty sure setuptools also installed it from pip as a
>   dependency of my application.

The cause of the problem is that the OP is combining 2 ways of installation: dnf and pip, which each compiles with different versions of Qt, compilation flags, etc. that can cause certain functionalities to fail. The solution is to uninstall PyQt5 by both methods and reinstall only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class DropTest(QtWidgets.QLabel):                       # - QWidget    + QLabel
    def __init__(self):
        super(DropTest, self).__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setText(" Accept Drops")
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : #ccd; color : blue; font-size: 20px;}")

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
#        print("DragEnter")
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
#        print("DragMove")
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
#        print("DropEvent")
#        position = e.pos()
#        print(position)

        self.setText(e.mimeData().text())                #  +++
        e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)                   #  +++

        e.accept()


class DragLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DragLabel, self).__init__()
        self.setText("Drag me")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            return
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setText(self.text())                     #   ("Test drop")
        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        dropAction = drag.exec(QtCore.Qt.CopyAction)


class Win(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Win, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 300, 400, 200)

        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(DragLabel())
        self.layout().addWidget(DropTest())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Win()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, not working either... What would differ though, apart from `QWidget -> QLabel`, in terms of logic?  Is my example working for you?

Comment: @Alex I noted the lines that I added: `# +++` - `self.setText(e.mimeData().text())`, `e.setDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)`. Your example does not work for me.

Comment: Sure but what would the logic behind it be? Just to understand the difference, cause I tried to literally copy-paste your code in a new file and it doesn't work either... Could my version of Qt have a bug? I just upgraded my OS to Fedora 31.